# Getting the cleaned_data of a CharField with Choice from Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to retrieve the data of a form that belongs to a CharField that uses choice in Django.

I have the following ***models.py***:

```
class Transaccion(models.Model):
    ref = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    fecha = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    usua = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    monto = models.FloatField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    TYPE_TRANS = (
        ('d', 'Debito'),
        ('c', 'Credito'),
    )
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_TRANS)
    LOAN_STATUS = (
        ('a', 'Aprobada'),
        ('e', 'Pendiente'),
        ('c', 'Rechazada'),
    )
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=LOAN_STATUS, blank=True, default='e')
    TYPE_BANCO = (
        ('BBVA', 'Bco BBVA Provincial'),
        ('BOD', 'Banco Occidental de Descuento'),
        ('MER','Bco Mercantil')
    )
    bco = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=TYPE_BANCO, blank=True)
```

The following ***forms.py***:

```
class GestionarTransaccionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaccion

        fields = [
            'usua',
            'fecha',
            'bco',
            'ref',
            'monto',
            'tipo',
            'estado',
        ]
        widgets={
            'usua': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': True}),
            'fecha': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': True}),
            'bco': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': True}),
            'ref': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': True}),
            'monto': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-contol', 'readonly': True}),
            'tipo': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': True}),
            'estado': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['ref'].disabled = True
        self.fields['fecha'].disabled = True
        self.fields['usua'].disabled = True
        self.fields['monto'].disabled = True
        self.fields['tipo'].disabled = True
        self.fields['bco'].disabled = True
```

And this ***views.py***:

```
class GestionarTransaccion(UpdateView):
    model = Transaccion
    form_class = GestionarTransaccionForm
    template_name = "administrador/gestionarT.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('transManager')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        u = User()
        if form.cleaned_data['estado']=='Aprobado':
            if form.cleaned_data['tipo']=='Credito':
                u.incrementarSaldo(form.cleaned_data['monto'], form.cleaned_data['usua']) 
            elif form.cleaned_data['tipo']=='Debito':
                u.disminuirSaldo(form.cleaned_data['monto'], form.cleaned_data['usua'])
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The problem appears when dealing with this little code snippet:

```
        if form.cleaned_data['estado']=='Aprobado':
            if form.cleaned_data['tipo']=='Credito':
                u.incrementarSaldo(form.cleaned_data['monto'], form.cleaned_data['usua']) 
            elif form.cleaned_data['tipo']=='Debito':
                u.disminuirSaldo(form.cleaned_data['monto'], form.cleaned_data['usua'])
```

It calls for a couple methods inside of the User *(methods that do work, because I tried them without the conditional and worked flawlessly)*, but it does nothing with the conditional. I get suspicious that the **cleaned_data** format isn't what I think it is, but trying with the code ('d' instead of 'Debito') does nothing at all. Any idea on how to work with this?

***EDIT***

Changed to

```
        if form.cleaned_data['estado']=='a':
            if form.cleaned_data['tipo']=='c':
                u.incrementarSaldo(form.cleaned_data['monto'], form.cleaned_data['usua']) 
            elif form.cleaned_data['tipo']=='d':
                u.disminuirSaldo(form.cleaned_data['monto'], form.cleaned_data['usua'])
```

And it magically worked, although I tried that and didn't work before.

Comment: Why you set the widgets disabled? Have you checked the value of form.cleaned_data['tipo']? Just print it out and see what is it.

Comment: I set them disabled because it's an UpdateView that can only update estado, but I wanted to show all the rest of the data. Print how?

Answer (score 1):

The value stored in the field is the first element in the choices tuple, not the second.

```
if form.cleaned_data['estado'] == 'a':
    if form.cleaned_data['tipo'] == 'c':
```

Comment: Well why don't you print the contents of `form.cleaned_data`?

Comment: Nevermind. I tried it again and it did work this time. Thank you so much!